# Most elegant approach for writing JSON data to a relational database using Django Models?

Tags: python, django, json, django-models, relational-database

I have a typical Relational Database model laid out in Django where a typical model contains some `ForeignKeys`, some `ManyToManyFields`, and some fields that extend Django's `DateTimeField`.

I want to save data that I am receiving in JSON format (not flat) from an external api. I wan't it such that data gets saved to respective tables (not the whole json string to one field). What is the most clean and simple approach to do this? Is there a library available to make this task simpler?

Here's an example to clarify my question,

**Models-**

```
class NinjaData(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)  
    birthdatetime = MyDateTimeField(null=True)
    deathdatetime = MyDatetimeField(null=True)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skills, null=True)
    weapons = models.ManyToManyField(Weapons, null=True)
    master = models.ForeignKey(Master, null=True)

class Skills(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    difficulty = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class Weapons(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    weight = models.FloatField(null=True)

class Master(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    is_awesome = models.NullBooleanField()
```

now, I typically have to save json string data that I obtain from an external api (secret ninja api) into this model, json looks like this

**JSON-**

```
{
"id":"1234",
"name":"Hitori",
"birthdatetime":"11/05/1999 20:30:00",
"skills":[
    {
    "id":"3456",
    "name":"stealth",
    "difficulty":"2"
    },
    {
    "id":"678",
    "name":"karate",
    "difficulty":"1"
    }
],
"weapons":[
    {
    "id":"878",
    "name":"shuriken",
    "weight":"0.2"
    },
    {
    "id":"574",
    "name":"katana",
    "weight":"0.5"
    }
],
"master":{
    "id":"4",
    "name":"Schi fu",
    "is_awesome":"true"
    }
}
```

now logic for handling a typical ManyToManyField is fairly simple,

**logic code -**

```
data = json.loads(ninja_json)
ninja = NinjaData.objects.create(id=data['id'], name=data['name'])

if 'weapons' in data:
    weapons = data['weapons']
    for weapon in weapons:
        w = Weapons.objects.get_or_create(**weapon)  # create a new weapon in Weapon table
        ninja.weapons.add(w)

if 'skills' in data:
    ...
    (skipping rest of the code for brevity)
```

There are many approaches that i could use,

- code above logic in the `view` function that does all the work of converting json to model instances
- code above logic overriding model's `__init__` method
- code above logic overriding model's `save()` method
- create a Manager for each model and code this logic inside each of its methods like `create`, `get_or_create`, `filter` etc.
- extend `ManyToManyField` and put it there,
- an external library?

I would like to know if there is a **single most obvious way** to save data in this json form to database without coding the above logic multiple times, what would be the most elegant approach that you would suggest?

Thanks all for reading the long post,

Comment: Thanks about detailed explanation, I will follow this thread. Only a joke(sorry about it): you can do this with a MS data adapter: da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con) , da.update(ninja_json). ;)

Comment: incidentally you don't need `id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)` on your models, Django already creates that field automatically. You can still supply out-of-sequence id values when creating a new instance https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#explicitly-specifying-auto-primary-key-values

Comment: Yes I already know that I don't need to add an id auto field, django does that for me. But, as I told earlier, I am saving data obtained from an external api, which already contains a unique Id field, which I will need when i use that api later.

Comment: In nowadays (2017) JSON *is* a store format: see [PostgreSQL 9.6+](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) and mature  JSONb datatype.... If [spring-boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) have good drivers, Django also can use good drivers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion the cleanest place for the code you need is as a new Manager method (eg from_json_string) on a custom manager for the NinjaData model.

I don't think you should override the standard create, get_or_create etc methods since you're doing something a bit different from what they normally do and it's good to keep them working normally.

**Update:**
I realised I'd probably want this for myself at some point so I have coded up and lightly tested a generic function. Since it recursively goes through and affects other models I'm no longer certain it belongs as a Manager method and should probably be a stand-alone helper function.

```
def create_or_update_and_get(model_class, data):
    get_or_create_kwargs = {
        model_class._meta.pk.name: data.pop(model_class._meta.pk.name)
    }
    try:
        # get
        instance = model_class.objects.get(**get_or_create_kwargs)
    except model_class.DoesNotExist:
        # create
        instance = model_class(**get_or_create_kwargs)
    # update (or finish creating)
    for key,value in data.items():
        field = model_class._meta.get_field(key)
        if not field:
            continue
        if isinstance(field, models.ManyToManyField):
            # can't add m2m until parent is saved
            continue
        elif isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey) and hasattr(value, 'items'):
            rel_instance = create_or_update_and_get(field.rel.to, value)
            setattr(instance, key, rel_instance)
        else:
            setattr(instance, key, value)
    instance.save()
    # now add the m2m relations
    for field in model_class._meta.many_to_many:
        if field.name in data and hasattr(data[field.name], 'append'):
            for obj in data[field.name]:
                rel_instance = create_or_update_and_get(field.rel.to, obj)
                getattr(instance, field.name).add(rel_instance)
    return instance

# for example:
from django.utils.simplejson import simplejson as json

data = json.loads(ninja_json)
ninja = create_or_update_and_get(NinjaData, data)
```

Comment: I have to move on with my work, so i am already making custom managers for my models, and i am already using a custom method inside it called create_or_update_and_get (name explains what it does), it takes the python object generated from json.loads(ninja_data) and using some 20-30 lines of magic returns an existing(updated) or newly created model instance. it is working out ok, but to be able to use standard methods like filter for lookups, i still have to override filter method. +1 for pointing exactly what i am doing, meanwhile, i am still looking for a more natural, scalable approach.

Comment: I don't quite get why you have to override filter for lookups? I guess to make the manage method more generic you could look through Manager.model._meta.fields for instances of ManyToMany and match those to keys in the json with list values, same for ForeignKey and keys with dict values. For each field you can get the related model class from eg `Manager.model._meta.fields[index].rel.to` and then get_or_create the related instances generically.

Comment: Awesome, with some tweaks it works perfectly, and it's one method to rule em all, this by far seems the cleanest way, thanks for the answer

Comment: cool, glad it works for you!  if any of the tweaks were bug fixes to the code above please share them, either here or on the djangosnippet I've copied it to http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2621/  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're familiar with the terminology, but what you're basically trying to do is *de-serialize* from a serialized/string format (in this case, JSON) into Python model objects.

I'm not familiar with Python libraries for doing this with JSON, so I can't recommend/endorse any, but a search using terms like "python", "deserialization", "json", "object", and "graph" seems to reveal [some Django documentation for serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) and the library [jsonpickle](https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle) on github.

Comment: However, it does claim to convert complex python objects to json and the other way round, there doesn't seem anything specific to django models, i'll read some more documentation on jsonpickle to see what can be done.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, Optimus has already worked out how to deserialize the json `json.loads(ninja_json)`

Comment: @Anentropic - though not the complete solution, Weston's post is helpful, json.loads(ninja_data) just converts to a python object, idealy, i would love it if, some library did this, ninjaDataInstacne = awesomejson.get_or_create(model=NinjaData, data=ninja_json) (given json and model follow a pattern), but life might not be that easy :(

Answer (score 1):

I've actually had this same need, and I wrote a custom database field to handle it. Just save the following in a Python module in your project (say, for instance, a `fields.py` file in the appropriate app), and then import and use it:

```
class JSONField(models.TextField):
    """Specialized text field that holds JSON in the database, which is
    represented within Python as (usually) a dictionary."""

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, blank=True, default='{}', help_text='Specialized text field that holds JSON in the database, which is represented within Python as (usually) a dictionary.', *args, **kwargs):
        super(JSONField, self).__init__(*args, blank=blank, default=default, help_text=help_text, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if type(value) in (str, unicode) and len(value) == 0:
            value = None
        return json.dumps(value)

    def formfield(self, form_class=JSONFormField, **kwargs):
        return super(JSONField, self).formfield(form_class=form_class, **kwargs)

    def bound_data(self, data, initial):
        return json.dumps(data)

    def to_python(self, value):
        # lists, dicts, ints, and booleans are clearly fine as is
        if type(value) not in (str, unicode):
            return value

        # empty strings were intended to be null
        if len(value) == 0:
            return None

        # NaN should become null; Python doesn't have a NaN value
        if value == 'NaN':
            return None

        # try to tell the difference between a "normal" string
        # and serialized JSON
        if value not in ('true', 'false', 'null') and (value[0] not in ('{', '[', '"') or value[-1] not in ('}', ']', '"')):
            return value

        # okay, this is a JSON-serialized string
        return json.loads(value)
```

A couple things. First, if you're using South, you'll need to explain to it how your custom field works:

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([], [r'^feedmagnet\.tools\.fields\.models\.JSONField'])
```

Second, while I've done a lot of work to make sure that this custom field plays nice everywhere, such as cleanly going back and forth between the serialized format and Python. There's one place where it doesn't quite work right, which is when using it in conjunction with `manage.py dumpdata`, where it coalesces the Python to a string rather than dumping it into JSON, which isn't what you want. I've found this to be a minor problem in actual practice.

More documentation on [writing custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-model-fields/).

I assert that this is the single best and most obvious way to do this. Note that I also assume that you don't need to do *lookups* on this data -- e.g. you'll retrieve records based on other criteria, and this will come along with it. If you need to do lookups based on something in your JSON, make sure that it's a true SQL field (and make sure it's indexed!).

Comment: -1: that's not what he's asking for. He's asking if there is an easy way of turning the JSON into model instances, when it's following a given standard format.

Comment: Thanks for writing a detailed answer but Chris is right,@Chris I am currently overriding __init__ () method of the NinjaData model, but it's a dirty hack.

Comment: @Luke - not only do I need to do lookups on the data, I need to write individual entities from JSON to apt table, I am working out if sub-classing ManyToManyField and ForeignKey is clean enough. any help is appreciated